# Multiple Arguments Excel

Tags: excel

I am needing the below formula to also allow for the argument of N to be Refused or Blank if no data is entered into the recording file. I keep running into the error of too many arguments and most logical things that I have tried have not worked.

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER([Recording.xlsx]Wednesday!$D$2:$D$26,[Recording.xlsx]Wednesday!$B$2:$B$26<>""),ROW()-2),"")="Y","Accepted","")
```

I am wanting to include the following:

```
="N","Refused","")
```

The formula needs to check the file for Y, N, or left blank. If Y it will return Accepted, if N will return refused, if no information is entered it will remain blank.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does the formula you posted above work fine? If it does, you could use an auxiliary cell to contain the output of `IFERROR`, and then do `=IF(<cell>="Y","Accepted",IF(<cell>="N","Refused",""))`. Or you can try with a [SWITCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e) function.

Comment: Right after I typed this out a response, I managed to get it working, I was making a major error in my logic but looking at what you commented allowed me to see it, what I ended up with `=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER([Recording.xlsx]Wednesday!$D$2:$D$26,[Recording.xlsx]Wednesday!$B$2:$B$26<>""),ROW()-2),"")="Y","Accepted",IF(IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER([Recording.xlsx]Wednesday!$D$2:$D$26,[Recording.xlsx]Wednesday!$B$2:$B$26<>""),ROW()-2),"")="N","Refused",""))`

Comment: But that's ugly, you are repeating the whole function! You should always try to avoid repeating stuff. I would very much use `SWITCH` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like commented above, I would use the SWITCH function:

```
=SWITCH(IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER([Recording.xlsx]Wednesday!$D$2:$D$26,[Recording.xlsx]Wednesday!$B$2:$B$26<>""),ROW()-2),""),"Y","Accepted","N","Refused","")
```

This way, you avoid using an auxiliary cell, and most importantly, avoid repeating the whole call to `IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER()))`.

Indented view for better understanding:

```
=SWITCH
 (
    IFERROR
    (
        INDEX
        (
            FILTER([Recording.xlsx]Wednesday!$D$2:$D$26,[Recording.xlsx]Wednesday!$B$2:$B$26<>""),
            ROW()-2
        ),
        ""
    ),
    "Y","Accepted",
    "N","Refused",
    ""
 )
```